# How do I capture popup dialog boxes in Marathon?

Tags: java, ruby

I've got some Marathon Java GUI testing code that works great except for when a dialog box pops up.  Recording didn't log anything when I ran through manually and execution of the Ruby script halts at that point waiting for me to manually click the dialog options.  How can I automate this portion?

Quick code sample:

```
# This works on the main window
with_window("Window") {
    select("Name", "Bob")
}

# This does nothing, even when embedded in the previous block
with_window("Dialog") {
    select("Inputarea", 20)
    click("OK")
}
```

Comment: What does marathon actually record? Can you post that part of the script?

Comment: There's nothing to post as Marathon fails to record any operations on the dialog in question.  Hence, I'm trying to manually write the code to do it.  Perhaps it's just a limitation in the current version of Marathon (or even the JRE/JDK as I see the Netbeans debugger interface doesn't handle popup dialogs correctly either).

Comment: Check whether there are any exceptions on the console. You can run marathon with '-i' option for not closing the command window. Try Ctrl+rightclick on any component of the window not being recorded and see whether the assertion window is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with it for a week or so, it's now working fine.  Appears to be magic as I've made no changes.  Same JRE/JDK, same marathon install, etc.  I'd rebooted with no change, yet it just works now...